# bootstrap nav bar not working on real devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, navbar

i have a problem with bootstrap.

I'm using typo3 and have 2 files, defaultLayout and the root.t3s:

root.t3s

```
    page = PAGE
page {
    includeCSS {
        file1 = path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

        file3 = path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
    }

    includeJS {
        file4 = path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.js

    }

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file.cObject = CASE
        file.cObject {
            key {
                data = levelfield: -1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
                override.data = TSFE:page|backend_layout
            }
            default = TEXT
            default.value = path/Templates/3columns.html

            1 = TEXT
            1.value = path/Templates/homepage.html

            2 = TEXT
            2.value = path/Templates/2columns.html

        }

        partialRootPath = path/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = path/Layouts/
        variables {
            companylogo = TEXT
            companylogo.value = <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>

            copyright = TEXT
            copyright {
                value = Copyright © Project {date:Y}
                insertData = 1
        }
        navigation_level1 =< lib.navigation_levl1
        navigation_level2 =< lib.navigation_levl2
        content_0 < styles.content.get
        content_1 < styles.content.getLeft
        content_2 < styles.content.getRight
        content_3 < styles.content.getBorder

        content_5 < styles.content.get
        content_5.select.where = colPos = 5
    }

    3000 = TEXT
    3000.value {
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/JavaScript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><{\/script>')</script>
<script src="path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>window.bootstrap || document.write('<script src="path/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.js"><{\/script>')</script>
    }
}
```

and here is my defaultLayout:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The defaultLayout is taken from [here](http://examples.getbootstrap.com/jumbotron/index.html):

Now the Problem, if i showing that in an normal browser on a desktop it's work fine. But if i test this site in an mobile browser on iphone oder nexus it doesnt show the collapse menu (it's look like in an normal browser).

After search on google i found a tool that resize your browser to mobile size and in this, the menu looks like i expected (the collapse menu is show but the button on thed right for open the menu is not working.

[thats](http://i40.tinypic.com/2lbgvf5.png) from the browser tool, it looks great but the button on the right isn't clickable

[thats](http://i42.tinypic.com/scsy04.png) from my mobilephone ....

I have no idea what i doing wrong, i hope anybody have suggestions.

thanks in advance.

regards

Comment: Can you post the url to your site?

Comment: I recommend the following steps for getting to the bottom of such issues: a) see if there are validation errors in the markup (I use http://html5.validator.nu), b) do a simple test to see if it's the entire media query that doesn't kick in (like setting background: red to body in the small screen stylesheet), so you can narrow down the problem and c) inspect the code directly on the phone with Safari or Adobe Edge Inspect. This is more tedious, but it's accurate. http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/ is awesome, but the results are still not 100% what you get on the phone.

Comment: @Michael sorry now it's only local, have you any idea it gaves something like temp webhoster for the html or anything? I try it to run it on the destination adresse/webhoster. Urs the tool u named, is that i have. i try the validator, thanks! have anybody other suggestions?